# Why in Windows I can run Kivy app.run() from within Twisted reactor.callInThread(), but not in OSX?

Tags: macos, twisted, kivy

It seems like if we develop a multithreaded application, we can't take it for granted that it'll run the same in other OSes.

I am developing a Kivy application, but this Kivy application is actually started from within a twisted reactor.callInThread(). This is the snippet of the code:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
def start_kivy():
    app = SomeKivyApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    reactor.callInThread(start_kivy)
    #it will open Kivy main application window in Windows, but not in OSX
    reactor.run()
```

The above snippet works awesomely in Windows. But in OSX: the Kivy main application window is not showing. Checking the log file, nothing wrong. No warning nor error occurred.

Any idea on how to solve this? Or, do you think I architected this application in the wrong way? That is, instead of making twisted take control of the main application loop, should I use Kivy application loop instead?

Comment: I don't use twisted, but you may find http://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html interesting for running twisted within kivy.

Comment: I have bad news for you.  Even if you develop a *single threaded* application you can't be sure it will run the same on every OS! :)

Comment: @inclement Yep, I actually have read it. But surely would love to know the reason why the above code is not running as expected

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone :D Got to say, it's probably the easiest error to notice in my assumption!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twisted uses different reactor implementations on different platforms - and the implementation used in Windows is Windows-specific and is not used on other platforms. So that is probably why it works on one platform and not another.

The right way to use Kivy and Twisted is in the [documentation](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/other-frameworks.html) inclement provided above. Kivy will iterate the Twisted loop from within Kivy's EventLoop. This works flawlessly - my Kivy application relies heavily on Twisted.

Comment: I think you were right about part the reactor implementation is OS specific. The above code run perfect for PyQt application (... but actually, it was a product designed on Windows only. Haven't tested it in OSX). I see.. let me applied the above documentation guide in my code. I may have to redesigned my app this way

Comment: I accepted @Ryan answer, although the exact code to be use is in this gist from https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/214, coming from the following github issue: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/214. I simply implement `_reactor_init()` and all of its dependent methods. After that the call to `reactor.callInThread` or `reactor.callFromThread` as Ryan said,works flawlessly: in OSX/Windows. To summarise this, in Windows, without installing Kivy reactor the program works fine. But it will not run on OSX. To make the application runs on both OSes, you must install Kivy provided reactor. Thanks!

Comment: @swdev you don't need to do that. `kivy.support.install_twisted_reactor()` was created by hansent using the code in his gist. They do pretty much the same thing, except the code in Kivy has been kept up to date with any bug fixes which the gist does not have.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! I will need to have a better look at my code then. At the moment the application runs fine (well, not sure if it'll encountered any bugs actually). Will inform about how it goes.